# How to call the map in Google Assistant directly?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

In this code, I called Google Assistant when I pressed the button(map)
How can I make it do a direct search for the nearest hospital?
i.e. I want to search on (near hospital ) directly  using my code.
is there method I can use to execute specific query for Google Assistant?
is there .. how can I use it ?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button  Map;
    String Text;

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Map = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Map);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        Map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Google_Assistant();
            }
        });

    }
    public  void Google_Assistant(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SECURE, true);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
            Text=("");

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unfortunately, this device does not support talk",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String query = "nearby hospitals";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH );
                        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
                        startActivity(intent);
```